# DevExpress ASPxGridView Fitlers

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I have DevExpress grid in the page.
For one column I enable filter in header of the table.
But by default Grid select the first filter expression.

What can I do to select another filter from C#?

With The Best Regards,
Alexander.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
ASPxGridView1.AutoFilterByColumn(ASPxGridView1.Columns["Department"], "%development");
```

http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=aspxgridview/customdocument3756.htm

For other task-based help, see here: http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=aspxgridview/CustomDocument3768.htm